# How is text and number giving me same output with RIGHT function in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, functions, datatypes

This is SALESMAN table in MySQL:

| Scode | Sname | Area | Qtysold | Dateofjoin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S001 | Ravi | North | 120 | 2015-10-01 |
| S002 | Sandeep | South | 105 | 2012-08-01 |
| S003 | Sunil | NULL | 68 | 2018-02-01 |
| S004 | Subh | West | 280 | 2010-04-01 |
| S005 | Ankit | East | 90 | 2018-10-01 |
| S006 | Raman | North | NULL | 2019-12-01 |

You can check it [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9bfb3b1267214a90bfa2b593451efe88) in dbfiddle.uk.

The output of `SELECT Sname FROM SALESMAN WHERE RIGHT(Scode,1)=5;` is:

```
+-------+
| Sname |
+-------+
| Ankit |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The output of `SELECT Sname FROM SALESMAN WHERE RIGHT(Scode,1)='5';` is:

```
+-------+
| Sname |
+-------+
| Ankit |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Scode column has CHAR datatype. So, output of `SELECT RIGHT(Scode,1) FROM SALESMAN` should be a text right? As far as I know, 5!='5'. Then how did the output of both the queries be same? Shouldn't output of `SELECT Sname FROM SALESMAN WHERE RIGHT(Scode,1)=5;` be an empty set as Scode has CHAR as datatype?

---

I used the logic from [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/309959) and ran `SELECT RIGHT(Scode,1) FROM SALESMAN;`. This is the output:

```
Field   1:  `RIGHT(Scode,1)`
Catalog:    `def`
Database:   ``
Table:      ``
Org_table:  ``
Type:       VAR_STRING
Collation:  cp850_general_ci (4)
Length:     1
Max_length: 1
Decimals:   31
Flags:


+----------------+
| RIGHT(Scode,1) |
+----------------+
| 1              |
| 2              |
| 3              |
| 4              |
| 5              |
| 6              |
+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So, the data type of output of `SELECT RIGHT(Scode,1) FROM SALESMAN;` is VAR_STRING. I guess VAR_STRING refers to VARCHAR.

Comment: [implicit conversion](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html) happens