# Code golf for handling subtraction with two null operands in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

All these 3 requests return NULL with MySQL 8 and SQLite 3.39:

```sql
SELECT 1 - NULL;
SELECT NULL - 1;
SELECT NULL - NULL;
```

But with PostgreSQL 15, the last one fails with:
`error: operator is not unique: unknown - unknown`

What is the shortest code to have PostgreSQL return NULL in last case?

(Note that with `SELECT a.x - a.y FROM a;`,
`x` and `y` may both be NULL.
PostgreSQL will not complain since it can determine the type from the column definitions.)

A simple solution is just:

```sql
SELECT CASE
   WHEN x IS NULL THEN NULL
   WHEN y IS NULL THEN NULL
   ELSE x - y
END;
```

Comment: I tested the results for MySQL and SQLite here since I only had a PostgreSQL at hand: https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a very short way that avoids duplicating the calculus of `x` and `y`, if there is one:

```sql
SELECT 0 + NULL - NULL;
```

Comment: I accepted my answer because technically it is still one character less than `SELECT NULL::int - NULL;`, and I must respect the code golf rules :).

Answer (score 1):

When sending the query as a string, postgres infers argument types from their text representation. If both arguments of "+" are NULL then it can't infer that your arguments are actually nullable integers.

Thus:

```
select null::int + null;
     Null
```

> All these 3 requests return NULL with MySQL 8 and SQLite 3.39

Type of returned value is part of the result. If you use the database from a language with strong typing, it's important to know the return type. The first two should return nullable int:

> ```
> SELECT 1 - NULL;
> SELECT NULL - 1;
> ```

But I don't know what the last one will return:

> ```
> SELECT NULL - NULL;
> ```

In MySQL you can set an [option in the client](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/309959/120712) to display the returned type.

Comment: Thanks :) You solution is slightly shortest that the equivalent `SELECT CAST (NULL AS integer) - NULL` that someone suggested before removing his answer.